# Symfony project not redirect me well, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

I'm doing a project with Synfony and I have included a button 'submit' which when pressed I must make an insert into my database and then must take or redirect to the "reportepreliminar.html" page using JavaScripts:

This is the code you use to redirect:

```
window.location.href = "reportepreliminar.html";
```

This is my home page where my button is:

**(1)** http://localhost/apis/web/app_dev.php/general/1

and this I want to get, when you press:

**(2)**  http://localhost/apis/web/app_dev.php/general/reportepreliminar.html

The problem is when I press the button, the URL changes to (2) but in the browser always displays the home page **(1)**.

I do not understand that you can be doing wrong?

regards

Comment: Any errors in console? What is `1` mapped to?

Comment: You *must* redirect the user with JavaScript? Why? Symfony has redirect methods in place to handle just this (as does PHP natively). What if the user has JS disabled? They're not redirecting anywhere `$this->redirect('/url_goes_here');`

Comment: Hello mplungjan, Marcus, so far has not given me any exception or error. I'm using javascripts because I have adapted much of my code to it, you could combine PHP with JS? thanks

Comment: You need to show the rendered html and how your script is called in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
window.location.href = "{{ path('route_name_of_reportepreliminar.html') }}";
```